# Prove $\ 1<\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+ ... + \frac{1}{3n+1}<2 $ using Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How do I prove this inequality

$$\ 1<\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+ ... + \frac{1}{3n+1}<2 $$

I've tried to prove that $$\ \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+ ... + \frac{1}{3n+1} \ $$ is less than $$\ \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+ ... + \frac{1}{n} \ $$ and that this sum is either less than $2$ or equal to $2$ using C-S.

Comment: Are you sure you need Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? It can be solved by simple algebraic manipulation.

Comment: The teacher asked us to try to solve it with Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ with $a_n = H_{3n+1}-H_n$ is an increasing sequence, convergent to its supremum, $\log(3)$. 
Since $a_1=\frac{13}{12}>1$ it is enough to show $\log(3)<2$ or $e^2>3$, which is trivial since $e^x > 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ for any $x>0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By C-S
$$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}+...+\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n+1}=$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{3n}\right)+...+\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)+\frac{1}{2n+1}>$$
$$>\frac{(1+1)^2}{4n+2}+\frac{(1+1)^2}{4n+2}+...+\frac{(1+1)^2}{4n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+1}=1.$$
The right inequality we can prove by the similar way:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}\frac{1}{n+k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n+k}+\frac{1}{3n+2-k}\right)+\frac{1}{2n+1}=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{4n+2}{(n+k)(3n+2-k)}+\frac{1}{2n+1}<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{4}{3n}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{5}{3}<2.$$

Comment: that's also Titu's lemma, right?

Comment: @Diana I don't like this naming. It's Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Is the sum 1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n greater than 1/n+1+1/n+2+...+1/3n+1?

Comment: @Diana Yes, of course! The first diverges and the second converges. By the way, post please your trying to solve your starting problem, otherwise this topic would be closed.

Answer (score 5):

**One Approach**

Simpler than Cauchy-Schwarz is to note that for $x\in(n,n+1)$,
$$
\frac1{n+1}\lt\frac1x\lt\frac1n\tag1
$$
which, when integrated in $x$ over $(n,n+1)$, gives
$$
\frac1{n+1}\lt\log\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)\lt\frac1n\tag2
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\frac1{k+1}
&\le\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\log\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)\\
&=\log\left(\frac{3n+1}n\right)\\[3pt]
&=\log\left(3+\frac1n\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\frac1{k+1}
&\ge\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\log\left(\frac{k+2}{k+1}\right)\\
&=\log\left(\frac{3n+2}{n+1}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\log\left(3-\frac1{n+1}\right)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Since $\log(4)\lt2$, inequality $(3)$ shows the upper bound for $n\ge1$.

Since $\log\left(\frac{11}4\right)\gt1$, inequality $(4)$ shows the lower bound for $n\ge3$. We need only verify the lower bound for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

---

**A Second Approach, Using Cauchy-Schwarz**

Simply multiplying the number of terms by the largest term gives
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\frac1{k+1}
&\le\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\\
&=2-\frac1{n+1}\\[9pt]
&\lt2\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Applying [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) gives
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\frac1{k+1}\sum_{k=n}^{3n}(k+1)
&\gt\left(\sum_{k=n}^{3n}1\right)^2\\
&=(2n+1)^2\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^{3n}(k+1)\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Equality does not hold in the first line of $(6)$ because the vectors are not parallel.

Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\frac1{k+1}\gt1\tag7
$$
Inequalities $(5)$ and $(7)$ show that
$$
1\lt\sum_{k=n}^{3n}\frac1{k+1}\lt2\tag8
$$

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative answer using $AM-HM$ inequality: $$\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n} \geq \frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_n}}$$

take $a_1=n+1, a_2=n+2,\cdots,a_{2n+1}=3n+1$, then by above inequality $$\frac{(n+1)+(n+2)+\cdots+(3n+1)}{2n+1} \geq \frac{2n+1}{\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n+1}}$$ Consequently, $$\frac{4n^2+4n+1}{2n+1} \geq \frac{2n+1}{\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n+1}}$$ which implies $$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3n+1} \geq \frac{(2n+1)^2}{4n^2+4n+1}=1$$

Comment: It can be said that this is also a solution using the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.  You can prove the AM-HM Inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Define

$$
f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}x^{n+k-1}=x^n\left(\frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1}\right)
$$

hence

$$
\int f_n(x) dx = \int x^n\left(\frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1}\right)dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1}
$$

and now apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality on $u(x) = x^n, v(x) = \frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1}$.